# Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin at}{t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Laplace transform of $\displaystyle \frac{\sin at}{t}$

My Attempt:

Rule used: $\displaystyle L[\frac{1}{t}f(t)]=\int_{s}^{\infty}\bar f(s)ds$ 
So,

$\displaystyle L[\frac{1}{t}\sin at]=\int_{s}^{\infty}\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}ds= \left. \tan^{-1}\frac{s}{a} \right|_{s}^{\infty}$

This is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\frac{s}{a}$

The given answer is $\displaystyle \cot^{-1}\frac{s}{a}$

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: How do I write the integral's last step(from s=s to s=\infty) properly (using the bar symbol) in latex ?

Comment: You didn't go wrong - they're equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\tan^{-1} x+\cot^{-1} x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I write the integral's last step(from s=s to s=\infty) properly (using the bar symbol) in latex ?

Comment: $$\left. \tan^{-1}\frac{s}{a} \right|_{s}^{\infty}$$