# Laplace tranform of $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to find the Laplace transform of

$$\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$

What I've tried: $\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt$ = $\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \sin(t) dt \int_0^\infty e^{-st} ds$  but I don't think this is correct as I am getting undefined results. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This question is a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928533/laplace-transform-of-frac-sin-att?rq=1

Comment: Your identity is based on no known property.

Comment: There is an alternate solution that I am going to describe.

Answer (score 1):

$L(\sin t) = \frac{1}{1+s^2}$. Hence $$L\left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right) = \int_s^\infty \frac{du}{u^2+1} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}{s} $$

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. I don't understand the justification though.

Comment: This is based on the following: If $L(f(t)) = F(s)$, then $L(\frac{f(t)}{t}) = \int_s^\infty F(u) du$.